# NodeJS and SQL Server : unable to connect when in a Docker Container

Tags: node.js, sql-server, docker, tedious

I have a NodeJS app that works fine when run standalone on a server. When I run it in a docker container it displays the following error message:

> ConnectionError: Failed to connect to TEXTREPLACED:undefined - socket hang up
>
> at /app/node_modules/mssql/lib/tedious/connection-pool.js:71:17
> at Connection.onConnect (/app/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1037:9)
> at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:514:26)
> at Connection.emit (node:events:394:28)
> at Connection.emit (/app/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1065:18)
> at Connection.socketError (/app/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1663:12)
> at Connection.socketEnd (/app/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1693:12)
> at Socket. (/app/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1433:14)
> at Socket.emit (node:events:406:35)
> at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1331:12) {
> code: 'ESOCKET',
> originalError: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to TEXTREPLACED:undefined - socket hang up
> at ConnectionError (/app/node_modules/tedious/lib/errors.js:13:12)
> at Connection.socketError (/app/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1663:56)
> at Connection.socketEnd (/app/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1693:12)
> at Socket. (/app/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1433:14)
> at Socket.emit (node:events:406:35)
> at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1331:12)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
> code: 'ESOCKET'
> }
> }

My connection code is:

```
const sqlConfig = {
        user: 'LOGIN',
        password: 'PASSWORD',
        server: 'SERVER\\INSTANCE',
        database: 'DATABASE',
        debug:true,
        port: 1433,
        driver:'tedious',
        pool:{
                idleTimeoutMillis: 1000
        },
        options:{
                port:1433,
                enableArithAbort:true,
                encrypt:true,
                trustServerCertificate:true,
                instanceName:'INSTANCE',
                database:'DATABASE',
                debug:{
                        packet: true,
                        data:true,
                        payload:true,
                        token:true,
                        log:true
                }
        }
};

const global_pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(sqlConfig);
var global_pool_con = null;

try {
        global_pool_con = global_pool.connect();
}catch{
        console.log(err);
}
```

Dockerfile

```
# Use Node base image 
FROM node:latest 
#ports 
EXPOSE 3000 
EXPOSE 1433 
WORKDIR /app 
COPY package.json /app 
RUN npm install 
COPY . /app 
USER node
CMD [run, script, release]
```

The "release" script runs the initial js file.

Confusingly the error shows "undefined" instead of a port number. I have used both host and bridge connections with the ports 1433 and 3000 (HAPI) routed and confirmed the ports are exposed in the dockerfile.

Considering that it works when standalone i'm presuming that a docker setting somewhere it's causing the issue.

Update: The TLS/SSL negotiation packet is being sent but is not received

```
State change: SentPrelogin -> SentTLSSSLNegotiation
```

Update: The SQL Server is displaying this error in the event logs when the dockerised app attempts to connect.

```
A fatal alert was generated and sent to the remote endpoint. This may result in termination of the connection. The TLS protocol defined fatal error code is 40. The Windows SChannel error state is 1205.

An TLS 1.2 connection request was received from a remote client application, but none of the cipher suites supported by the client application are supported by the server. The SSL connection request has failed.
```

Comment: when using containers you open\route ports around the container only when trying to connect to the container itself, if using a bridge network or sharing the network setting of the host machine you should be able to access everything your host machine can. Also, what error is showing undefined, and are you able to include it as well? could it be you incorrectly configured docker network settings, on what os and version did you install docker and how?

Comment: `server: 'SERVER\\INSTANCE'` and `port: 1433`? Have you tried removing the instance name (from both places you use it)? When instance names are involved in client connection strings the SQL Server Browser service is required to resolve the instance name to a TCP port number - and the Browser service itself listens on udp/1434 which is something you can't expose/publish from Docker containers.

Comment: Do you try to reach the `server\instance` from the container? The `server\instance` is another container or is it on the host?

Comment: @NoamYizraeli The error message is the first code clip in the post, the first line should read <server_name>:<port> but the port number is showing as undefined, even though it has been? Docker is running on Ubuntu Server 20.4 with installation followed from the Docker website

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I have tried removing both, no luck I'm afraid. I have the browser service running.

Comment: @Max The SQL server is another machine all together, as in my post the app works fine when run on the docker host, it's only when put into a container that I get the error. This leads me to think my app code is correct but Docker that is having the issue.

Comment: Can you add the Dockerfile?

Comment: @Max no worries. # Use Node base image
FROM node:latest

#ports
EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 1433

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app

RUN npm install

COPY . /app

USER node

Comment: I have updated the question with your Dockerfile; it seems that you don't have an ENTRYPOINT or CMD on your docker file, do you pass one of these from the command line when running? In this case, update the question with the docker command line you use.

Comment: @Max thanks, I have no idea how you do that. Yes CMD is passed at runtime, docker file in question updated.

Comment: @Max I have enabled some debugging options and found that when in the docker container the prelogin packet is sent for TLS/SSL negotiation but then not received? Error message in question

Comment: do you have firewalld or iptables service running that could prevent only the container from sending udp on 1433?

Comment: @NoamYizraeli no firewalls will be blocking it, did check

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone for your help.

The resolution for this was to update the openSSL.cnf file, it had additional lines in it from the source image that weren't required.